# Getting mobile version of a web page instead of the desktop version with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, phantomjs

I am using headless firefox on Debian remote server in order to get some data scraped with selenium webdriver and passed to scrapy later on. Instead of getting a desktop version I am getting a mobile version of the web page from where I am trying to scrap data from. I need the desktop version! I understand that I need to send proper user agent string and this is how I do:

```
def call_via_proxy(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT):
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        # Direct = 0, Manual = 1, PAC = 2, AUTODETECT = 4, SYSTEM = 5
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http",PROXY_HOST)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
        fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")
        fp.update_preferences()
        return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
#create webdriver
driver = call_via_proxy("us.proxymesh.com","31280")
driver.get(response.url)
```

The code works fine on my desktop machine (win7) but on the server (debian) where the code needs to run I am getting a mobile version of the web page. Same happens if I use phantomJS.

```
    #set user agents for PhantomJS
    user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) ")
    dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = user_agent
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-i686/bina/phantomjs',desired_capabilities=dcap)
    driver.get(response.url)
```

Is there a way to get HTTP response code from a web page with selenium? I wonder what is wrong here? I don't believe it has something to do with platform dependency?? Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried confirming that the user-agent is changed? For example using http://httpbin.org/user-agent

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem with some mobile responsive templates that go from screen size. Phantom appears to have its own set of rules for me in this instance. Forcing a Desktop Browser Size (`driver.manage().window.size`) appears to work for me.

I have no Java code for this, but in C# this would be:

```
_driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1024,768);
```

I seem to recall that there is a `Dimensions` value you might be able to pass instead. I do this and the desktop page appears once more!

Comment: Java will look like this `driver.manage().window().fullscreen()`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue myself. I had the `userAgent` set, but not the [`viewportSize`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html). The default is 400x300. Once I set this, I was able to get the desktop version.

Here is a JS example implementation which you should be able to fit into your solution.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

//This is the Chrome 55 UA.
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36';

//THE ANSWER. This is just my test server resolution.
page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1600,
  height: 900
};

page.open('http://www.example.com', function(status) {

  if(status === "success") {
    //Saves an image of the page.
    page.render('example.png');
  }

  //Tidy up.
  phantom.exit();
});
```